# Cypress Testing Organization

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to have my unit tests created with Cypress in my component directories and/or is it possible to link them as opposed to having them in the Cypress folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Cypress documentation:](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Test-files)

> Test files are located in cypress/integration by default, but can be configured to another directory.

Then on ['Configuration' documentation page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files) you may find option *integrationFolder*, which specifies the path to the folder containing integration test files, and by default its value is *cypress/integration*.

So you just have to change *integrationFolder* option in *cypress.json* file.

Comment: This sounds like you still have to have your tests in a single directory as opposed to having them living in the many different component directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Cypress grab tests that are spread across multiple directories by modifying your `cypress.json`.

For example, if you want to grab all tests from the `src/pages` and `src/components` directories that have `.spec.` in them, you could update your `cypress.json` to be:

```json
{
  "integrationFolder": "./",
  "testFiles": "{./src/pages/**/*.spec.*,./src/components/**/*.spec.*}"
}
```

(from [this discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2120))